# Draw a rotor in 3d using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, 3d

I have the following code whcih describes a system with a rotor and a generator

[image]

The code is the following

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                bending, 
                calc, chains, 
                decorations.pathmorphing,  % added
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%% viewing angles %%
\def\angThe{70}   %%
\def\angPhi{50}   %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tdplotsetmaincoords{\angThe}{\angPhi}

\tikzset
{
  rotor/.pic={
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,rotate=90,line width=.2pt]
      \def\r{3.1}
      \def\z{2}
      %\draw [very thick,blue] (0,0,-\z-2) -- (0,0) ;
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\angPhiOpp}{\angPhi-180}

      \draw [fill=gray!20] (\angPhi:\r) arc (\angPhi:\angPhiOpp:\r) 
      {[shift={(0,0,-\z)}]
                        -- (\angPhiOpp:\r) arc (\angPhiOpp:\angPhi:\r) 
      } -- cycle;
      \begin{scope}
        \draw [clip] (0,0) circle (\r) ;
        \fill [gray!20] (0,0) circle (\r) ;
        \draw [fill=gray!60,even odd rule] (0:\r) circle (\r) 
           (120:\r) circle (\r)
           (240:\r) circle (\r) 
           (0,0) circle (2*\r);
      \end{scope}
      %\draw [very thick,blue] (0,0,2) -- (0,0) ;
    \end{scope}
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
    box/.style = {draw,fill=blue!20!white, line width=1mm,rounded               corners, font=\linespread{0.75},align=center, inner sep=10mm, outer     sep=0pt, on chain},
    axs/.style = {draw, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=0.1mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 on chain, node contents={}},
    arr/.style = {color=#1, line width=0.8mm,
                 shorten >=-1mm, shorten <=-1mm,
                 -{Stealth[length=1.6mm,width=3mm,flex=1.2]},
                 bend angle=60},
    spring/.style = {thick, decorate,       % new, 
                 decoration={zigzag,pre length=3mm,post                                     length=3mm,segment length=6}
                },
    ellipse/.style = {draw,minimum size=100pt,align=center,on chain},                       
  damper/.pic = {\coordinate (-east);   % new
                 \coordinate[left=1mm of -east] (-west);
                 \draw[very thick] ($(-east)+(0,2mm)$) -- ++ (0,-4mm);
                 \draw[thick]  ($(-east)+(0,3mm)$) -| ++ (-1mm,-6mm) -- ++ (1mm,0);
                 },
shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1},
]
    % blocks (boxes)
\node (n1) [label=below:$J_M$] {};
\pic (rotor) at (n1.south) {rotor};
%\node (n1) [box,label=below:$J_M$]  {Rotor};
%\node (n1) [ellipse,label=below:$J_M$]  {Rotor};
\node (n2) [axs];
%\node (n3) [box]                    {$\tau$};
%\node (n4) [axs];
\node (n2) [minimum height=6mm,minimum width=12mm,
            label={[yshift= 1mm]above:$K$},
            label={[yshift=-3mm]below:$D$},
            on chain] {};% for spring and dumper
\node (n3) [axs];
\node (n4) [box,label=below:$J_G$,fill=blue!20!white,rounded corners]  {Generator};
    % spring and damper, added
\draw[ultra thick,shorten <>=-2mm]
    (n2.north west) -- (n2.south west);
\draw[ultra thick,shorten <>=-2mm]
     (n2.north east) -- (n2.south east);
\draw[spring]   (n2.north west) -- (n2.north east);
\pic (dmp) at (n2.south)  {damper};
\draw(n2.south west) -- (dmp-west)  (dmp-east) -- (n2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The thing is that I would like to plot two rounded boxes with an elipse in the form illustrated below. Please note that the blades pictured can be omitted.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at this : [a cylinder using tikz-3dplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385943/illustrating-drawing-in-3d-using-tikz/385950#385950). Basically draw your circular section normally (in the xy-plane), then apply the `tikz-3dplot` transformation, and draw the thickness of the cylinder. Also [more explanations about tikz-3dplot here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388621/optimizing-perspective-tikz-graphic/388626#388626). In your case, you would probably do this in a `\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]...\end{scope}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not compiling, since you didn't provide a full MWE.

See if the following is of some help :

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

%% viewing angles %%
\def\angThe{70}   %%
\def\angPhi{50}   %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tdplotsetmaincoords{\angThe}{\angPhi}

\tikzset
{
  rotor/.pic={
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,rotate=90,line width=.2pt]
      \def\r{3.1}
      \def\z{2}
      \draw [very thick,blue] (0,0,-\z-2) -- (0,0) ;
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\angPhiOpp}{\angPhi-180}

      \draw [fill=pink] (\angPhi:\r) arc (\angPhi:\angPhiOpp:\r) 
      {[shift={(0,0,-\z)}]
                        -- (\angPhiOpp:\r) arc (\angPhiOpp:\angPhi:\r) 
      } -- cycle;
      \begin{scope}
        \draw [clip] (0,0) circle (\r) ;
        \fill [gray!20] (0,0) circle (\r) ;
        \draw [fill=blue!20,even odd rule] (0:\r) circle (\r) 
           (120:\r) circle (\r)
           (240:\r) circle (\r) 
           (0,0) circle (2*\r);
      \end{scope}
      \draw [very thick,blue] (0,0,2) -- (0,0) ;
    \end{scope}
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {rotor};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code but I hav problems while picturing this as my first node intead of my box. How can I concatenate this rotor with the other elemens with a chain then?

Comment: @JPV Can you provide a compilable mwe ? I'll probably have time to try and help on friday.

Comment: I have edited the question with the full code. Can you look at it now? Thanks a lot.